# show and hide with media query

Tags: html, css

given that I have two divs with two classes; .cat & .rat, I want:

Computer view:
.cat is hiding
.rat is showing

Mobile view
.cat is showing
.rat is hiding

These are my codes but seem I can't make it happen.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    .cat
    {display: none;}
    }

    .rat
    {width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    }


@media screen and (min-width: 0px) {

    .cat
        {width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: red;
        }

    .rat
    {display: none;}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="cat"></div>
<div class="rat"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a mistake there. it should be .cat instead.

Comment: min-width:0 and min-width: 600px both satisfy the condition and .cat css override in it. use max-width: 600px for mobile

Comment: Just a pointer but I dont see the closing braces for the media queries. Rest seems fine to me

Answer (score 2):

It's so easy:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .cat
    {
      display: none;
    }
    .rat
    {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: green;
      display:block;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .cat
    {
       width: 300px;
       height: 300px;
       background-color: red;
       display:block;
    }
    .rat
    {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue you have is that the both the condition satisfy so it overrides it and use max-width condition. instead of that you can try below code.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    .cat
    {display: none;}
    }

    .rat
    {width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    }


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .cat
        {width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: red;
        }

    .rat
    {display: none;}

}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="cat"></div>
<div class="rat"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we set desktop-first design. So first set up desktop CSS:

```
.rat {
   display: block;
}

.cat {
   display: none;
}
```

Now invert it when screen is smaller than 600px:

```
.rat {
   display: block;
}

.cat {
   display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .rat {
       display: none;
    }

    .cat {
       display: block;
    }
}
```

`max-width` means every screen size that is smaller or same width as our set value. (<= 600)

`min-width` means every screen size that is bigger or same width as our set value (>= 600)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the **css for desktop** **without media queries** and in that case rat will show and cat will hide.

```
.rat {
  display: block;
}

.cat {
  display: none;
}
```

Then in your **media query for mobile** you can hide rat and show cat. Here `max-width:600px` specify the **width below 600px** , **so this css will come in existence when device width is less than 600**.

> Here is an compiled example:

```css
.rat {
  display: block;
}

.cat {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .rat {
    display: none;
  }
  .cat {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rat"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/green/fff&text=Rat" /></div>
<div class="cat"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0000/fff&text=Cat" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

**1 Using bootstrap [hidden classes](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="hidden-lg cat">Cat</div>
    <div class="hidden-xs rat">Rat</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**2. Using media query**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
        .rat {
            display: block;
        }
        
        .cat {
            display: none;
        }
        
        @media (max-width:600px) {
            .rat {
                display: none;
            }
            .cat {
                display: block;
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="cat">Cat</div>
    <div class="rat">Rat</div>

</body>

</html>
```